# On telnet session file edit not happening using vi editor

Tags: bash, shell, kernel, terminal-server

I used rlwrap because with telnet session arrow keys were not working, after starting telnet session with rlwrap am not able to edit the file in using vi editor.

Whether its problem with rlwrap.If i don't use arrow keys wont work in my telnet session.

Comment: Am running termnetd 3.2 terminal server application.I used rlwrap because arrow keys was not working.But now am not able to edit the files using VI.Let me know your thoughts.

Answer (score 1):

how do you mean the arrow keys wont work?

is it a terminal emulation problem?

you should be able to use hjkl instead of the arrow keys in vi.